# Substitute with `...` multiline output of find command

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, osx, command-substitution

I need to substitute output of `find` command to another command to process every found file, e.g.:

```
mdls `find ~/target_dir/ -iname '*some*' -depth 1`
```

(`mdls` is a command in OS X which get metadata attributes of the specified file. It doesn't support piping thus `find ... | mdls` fails.)

The command above works fine, but expectedly fails on files with spaces in name. I thought that adding quotes via `sed` helps with it:

```
$ find ~/target_dir/ -iname '*some*' -depth 1 | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/'
"/Users/shau-kote/target_dir//secondsomefile"
"/Users/shau-kote/target_dir//some file with spaces in name"
"/Users/shau-kote/target_dir//somefile"
```

Alack, now my `mdls` command fails on all files:

```
$ mdls `find ~/target_dir/ -iname '*some*' -depth 1 | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/'`
"/Users/shau-kote/target_dir//secondsomefile": could not find "/Users/shau-kote/target_dir//secondsomefile".
```

How can I fix it so as `mdls` do correctly process all file names from `find`?

Thank you.

**P.S.** I'm not sure is it important or self-evident, but

```
mdls "/Users/shau-kote/target_dir//secondsomefile"
```

works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find`'s `-exec` command:

```
find ~/target_dir/ -iname '*some*' -depth 1 -exec mdls {} \;
```

This will run `mdls` on every matching filename found by `find`.  It will work with any filename, even those containing spaces or newlines etc.

if `mdls` can work with multiple filenames on the command line, you could terminate the `-exec` command with `+` instead of `\;`.  e.g.

```
find ~/target_dir/ -iname '*some*' -depth 1 -exec mdls {} +
```